# Why the image does not appear in footer?

Tags: html, laravel, laravel-5

My code of footer view is like this :

```
...
<div class="col-md-4">
  <a href="{{url('/')}}"><img src="images/dwi.png" alt="Travel Agency Logo" /></a>
</div>
...
```

I have a few pages. On the home page, the image appear. But on another page, the image does not appear. Whereas all pages using the same view footer. 
Why the image only appears on the home page?

Thank you

Comment: @mustaccio, In my opinion, this question relates to laravel. So, tags or caption laravel not need to be removed. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using the `asset` function:

`<img src="{{ asset(images/dwi.png) }}" alt="Travel Agency Logo" />`

See: https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/helpers#method-asset

Comment: Thank you for answering my question. The above code less single quotes. I fix the code above to be like this : `<img src="{{ asset('images/dwi.png') }}" alt="Travel Agency Logo" />`

Answer (score 1):

Add a slash (/) before images in img src. The image (I guess) does only load when the page is in parent folder (/) and that's exactly logic.

Comment: It is not working. Instead, the images on the home page does not appear

Comment: Well you never mentionnned that you are using the laravel assets.